# Xcode can only refactor C and Objective-C code. How to rename swift class name in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode6, xcode9

I have created a new Single View Application Project in Xcode 6 beta version. I want to rename swift class from `ViewController.swift` to some other name. But when I select Refactor -> Rename, it gives error `Xcode can only refactor C and Objective-C code`.

[image]

Any idea how to rename swift class in Xcode 6?

**UPDATE:**

Finally Xcode 9 is supporting Refactoring for Swift. It took Apple 3 years to add this basic feature. [Refactoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/xcode_9/xcode_9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004626-CH8-SW11)

Comment: There is none currently. [File a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Over a year after this was asked, the only answer is still a manual find and replace! Unbelievably backwards of Apple, this is a basic and essential feature for an IDE

Comment: AppCode can accomplish this refactoring. It will be a two-step process for your class defined in a `.swift` file.

1. Select the class name and perform **Refactor > Rename**.

2. Select the `.swift` file and perform **Refactor > Rename**.

Comment: Even after two years!!! NOT IMPLEMENTED???

Comment: It's actually nice in a way brings back memories of old times while copy and pasting 100 items in C

Answer (score 25):

You can change name of a class in File Inspector at the right side of Xcode6.

- open your class
- go to File Inspector > Identify and type section
- rename existing class in "name" field.

That's all! Previously I manually rename the class name in the class file.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it only changes the class name only in file structure. I still have to change all instances of my class name everywhere in code. Whereas using Refactor->Rename... used to change name in file structure as well as in code.

Comment: No problem! I just thought its a kind of a solution until Apple do something with this issue. You can use the Find and Replace function as well until that day. Any case, built in Refactor->Rename almost does the same actions.

Comment: @Newone It doesn't do the same thing. For instance, Find and Replace will search inside of strings, and Refactor->Rename should not do that.

Answer (score 15):

I've been using *Find>Find & Replace in Project*, it's not perfect but it works.

Answer (score 12):

I use this way:

- You can positioning the cursor on the variable that you want rename
- Select Editor - Edit all in Scope (^⌘E)
- Rename the variable and automatically all variable occurrences is edit

Comment: This helps. I'm amazed that I missed this for so long!! :]

Comment: This only works within the scope, i.e. not across files IIRC.

Answer (score 10):

[From this tutorial.](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/developing-ios8-apps-using-swift-part-3-best-practices/)

## Split up your iOS8 Swift Code

> First things first, let’s rename our View Controller to be something more meaningful. Open up your ViewController.swift file and replace all references to ‘ViewController’ with our new name, ‘SearchResultsViewController’. Rename the file as well to SearchResultsViewController.swift.
>
> If you try to run the app from here you’ll get a crash. This is because our storyboard file hasn’t been updated to know about the new class! So open up the Main.storyboard, select your ‘View Controller’ object in the scene (the left-hand side nav), and then select the Identity Inspector (right-hand side, third button.)
>
> From here let’s change the class from ‘ViewController’ to ‘SearchResultsViewController’. Now we should be back on track. Check that the project still works, and let’s proceed.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have already experimented this method. But it doesn't seems to be good way. If I am using ViewController.swift objects in 10 classes, I have to manually rename them in all classes. So much painful and waste for time :(

Comment: @Khawar- Yes you are right ,, but might be there is not another option now and also swift is in beta so. don't worry about it .. hope apple will find another more easy way then (objective c ???) :)

Comment: I'm on Version 7.2 (7C68) and the renaming refactoring is still not possible

Comment: In 7.3 its also not possible.

Answer (score 3):

## Xcode 9

Xcode 9 now supports renaming in Swift. This was announced in WWDC 2017.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, thank you Apple, but renaming still doesn't work. Now it is crashing the Xcode.

Comment: True... As of Version 9.0 beta, renaming makes Xcode crash. But this is what's supposed to work in the _future_, whenever that may be :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Apple hasn't gotten around to implementing it yet.

See http://www.quora.com/Why-isnt-there-a-refactoring-feature-for-Swift-language-in-Xcode-6 for more information.