# How do I refactor Swift in Xcode?

Tags: swift, refactoring, xcode7

Is there a way to refactor swift in Xcode 7.1?

When I try to rename a variable (e.g. highlight, right-click, refactor > rename), Xcode pops up an error dialog saying:

> Can't refactor Swift code. Xcode can only refactor C and Objective-C code.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: At present, you can't. Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133664/xcode-can-only-refactor-c-and-objective-c-code-how-to-rename-swift-class-name-i.

Comment: It is beyond insane that in 2016, a major IDE cannot handle such a basic task as refactoring. In 1995 with Visual Basic 3 I was able to refactor.

Comment: Same issue continues to Xcode 8. :(

Comment: Why Apple won't improve on this? Honestly Xcode is far behind the other major IDE already.

Comment: Xcode 9 promises the refactoring of Swift. Release note of Xcode 9:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/xcode_9/xcode_9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004626-CH8-SW2

Comment: @Shad it was about time :)

Comment: Please update the accepted answer

Answer (score 86, accepted):

AFAIK the refactoring is not working with Swift right now, however, at least in the same file(scope), you can do the following:
[image]

Comment: How did you record your screen?

Comment: @Mohamad wirh LICEcap

Comment: I'm looking very much forward to "real" refactoring being introduced to Swift in Xcode. Until then, this is by far the best solution I've seen! Thank you @Dániel Nagy

Comment: You can do what? How did you get that dropdown?

Comment: @TimSim if you click on a variable and then keep the cursor over it for a second, it will appear on the right side, or Editor -> Edit All in Scope

Comment: The short key for this is cmd+ctrl+E after selection.

Answer (score 14):

## Xcode 9 - 10

Xcode 9 now supports refactoring in Swift. This was announced in WWDC 2017.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The lack of refactoring is astounding (especially as I am coming off of a major stint using VS)  However I have just noticed that someone has done something about it.  On GitHub there is [Refactorator Xcode Plugin](https://github.com/johnno1962/Refactorator) (MIT license) which claims:

> Refactorator is an Xcode plugin for refactoring Swift & now
>   Objective-C code. It will rename public or internal vars, functions,
>   enums etc. For private and local entities use Xcode's existing "Edit
>   All in Scope" functionality.

Full disclosure is that I have nothing to do with them and am just about to install the product myself.

Comment: I’ve had no luck with it. For example to rename a variable it may pick up most, but not all usages (why?) - find and replace gets 100%. I’ve not been impressed.

Answer (score 2):

As of Xcode 7.2 beta the refactoring tools do not support Swift.

What I do is use the type checker. Change the name/type of something and then fix all the compile breakages. Because of the strong typing you can have more confidence that this approach will catch everything. I have at times deliberately changed things and broken them temporarily to check where objects or types are used or accessed from.

Or use AppCode for the refactoring, I hear it is good but haven't tried much myself.