# Change all instances of a Class at once in Xcode (IB + files)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, class

I have a well advanced project in Swift on Xcode. After a while I decided to add a custom property (to catch a UIColor) to UIButton Class by subclassing it. But I already have a whole bunch of buttons in my Interface Builder set and programmatically in my project itself.

Is there a clean way to change each instances of my old UIButton Class, in IB and in the project files, to my new one at once without messing everything ? Hope I have been clear... ;) Thanks a lot

Comment: You may be able to use the Refactor tooling in Xcode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497338/how-do-i-refactor-swift-in-xcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this outside of Xcode with the help of some shell scripting.
First, do a backup.

Then something like:

```
for f in `find . -name \*.storyboard -o -name \*.xib` ; do
cp $f $f.orig
sed 's/<button/<button customClass="MyButton" customModule="MyModule" customModuleProvider="target"/g' $f.orig > $f
done
```

Check if everything still works in Xcode (if not, you still have a backup in the .orig files)

Lastly you might also want to change some classes in your Code from `UIButton` to `MyButton`, but this cannot be automated since your code might reference some framework classes that sill will remain `UIButton`s.

Answer (score 0):

Actually not pretty clear but note that if you looking for clean way to effect for all instances is using **Type properties** like `static` and `class` will be good idea